# How to insert multiple rows in a dataframe in python without changing the Index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe , How can i insert a row with Twith multiple values such that the index always starts with 0.

df:

```
   Topics_numberrs_k    Topics_assignment_k
0   0                   Int64Index([ 175, 920, 1016, 2068, 2162, 3385]
1   1                   Int64Index([ 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Expected output:

```
    Topics_numberrs_k   Topics_assignment_k
0   -1                  NaN
1    0                  Int64Index([ 175, 920, 1016, 2068, 2162, 3385]
2    1                  Int64Index([ 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
i_row = [-1, "NaN"]

df.iloc[0] = i_row
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with new DataFrame and append existing:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[-1, np.nan]], columns=df.columns), df], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   Topics_numberrs_k                             Topics_assignment_k
0                 -1                                             NaN
1                  0  Int64Index([ 175, 920, 1016, 2068, 2162, 3385]
2                  1                  Int64Index([ 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or create new row and sorting index by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), if necessary convert `Topics_numberrs_k` to integers:

```
df.loc[-1] = [-1, np.nan]

df = df.sort_index(ignore_index=True).astype({'Topics_numberrs_k':'int'})
print (df)
   Topics_numberrs_k                             Topics_assignment_k
0                 -1                                             NaN
1                  0  Int64Index([ 175, 920, 1016, 2068, 2162, 3385]
2                  1                  Int64Index([ 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```